# How do you load another page with ajax with a link within ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a few levels that are loaded with ajax and currently the level menu is on the right and need it to be in the content area instead. I'm not sure how to have a click event within the ajax loaded content load another level in it's own content div. Teh code I'm working with is here:

```
var $level = $('#navigation a'),// Links on the right
    last = null;// Last Level

$level.click(function(){
    if( last != this ){ // let's avoid needless requests
        var url = 'html/' + this.hash.slice(1) + '.html';
        $('#content').html( '<p class="loading">Loading...</p>' ).load( url, function(){
            this.scrollLeft = 0;//scroll back to the left
        });
    }
    last = this;
    this.blur(); // Remove the awful outline
    return false;
});

$level.eq(0).click(); // Load the first Level
```

The end goal is to have the user be able to tap on images within the content area (that's ajax loaded) to navigate within that level, or to load another level (.html page). What I'm trying to avoid is to have to declare every instance of every level within the script as there will be more than 5.

my test environment is here: http://www.beingproperties.com/test/jscroll-ajax/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! -Chris

Comment: To make an event work  that was loaded by ajax you have to use live, For example $('#mydiv').live('click', function(e){ your codes });

Comment: So how would the above code be rewritten. I have read through this information here (http://beski.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/jquery-ajax-link-inside-ajax-loaded-content-problem/), though am unclear how to write it so that I don't have to define each page load.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code from binding to the click event directly to use the live-binding.

Instead of this:

```
$level.click(function() {
```

You should use this:

```
$level.live('click', function() {
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+ the correct syntax would be:

```
$('#navigation').on('click', 'a', function() {
```